# C++ primer enums and implicit conversion

Tags: c++, enums, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

Hello I have this from C++ primer 5th edition:

> `// unscoped enumeration; the underlying type is machine dependent`
>
> `enum Tokens {INLINE = 128, VIRTUAL = 129};`
>
> `void newf(unsigned char);`
>
> `void newf(int);`
>
> `unsigned char uc = VIRTUAL;`
>
> `newf(VIRTUAL); // calls newf(int)`
>
> `newf(uc); // calls newf(unsigned char)`
>
> The `enum` Tokens has only two enumerators, the larger of which has the value `129`. That value can be represented by the type `unsigned char`, and many compilers will use `unsigned char` as the underlying type for Tokens. Regardless of its underlying type, objects and the enumerators of `Tokens` are promoted to `int`. Enumerators and values of an `enum` type are not promoted to `unsigned char`, even if the values of the enumerators would fit.

- But If I explicitly specify the underlying type that matches exactly the integral value of the function parameter, then I think no implicit conversion will take place:

  ```
  enum days : unsigned char{sat = 1, sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri};

  void foo(unsigned char x){
      std::cout << "foo(unsigned char)\n";
  }

  void foo(int){
     std::cout << "foo(int)\n";
  }

  foo(tue); // foo(unsigend char)
  ```

So as you can see the enumerator value `tue` is not promoted to `int` and I get the version of `foo(unsigned char)` and not `foo(int)`.

- So does he mean if the enumeration underlying type differs from the function parameter then enumerators are not promoted to `char` but to `int` or large integral types?
- I think in his example of `enum tokens` if the underlying type is `unsigned char` then there will be no integral promotion in the function call: `newf(VIRTUAL); // calls newf(int)` and the version of `newf(unsigned char)` is selected. What you think?

Comment: Unrelated: Why the sudden spike in interest in the quirks of a ten year old programming text? Universities finally decide to update their syllabuses to this millennium, but figure they should only go half-way?

Comment: "I think no implicit conversion will take place". Have you tried running the code yourself? Do the results differ from your expectations and you'd like to know why? Do the results conform to your expectations but you'd like confirmation that your reasoning is correct?

Comment: I think you're mixing things up. In the case of an `enum` with an unspecified type, promotion may have to take place, but since you didn't use an `enum` with an unspecified type and instead asked for `unsigned char` by name, `unsigned char` looks to be a better fit. It could promote, but there's no need here.

Comment: And perhaps We're both looking at it from too recent a C++ standard to really see the point the book is trying to make. Lemme write up a hack example to see what happens.

Comment: I think we're wandering into implementation-defined behaviour. I need to do some standard diving to find out for sure, and I don't have time for that right now. Quick hack: https://godbolt.org/z/7P73PfxKq I hope you get a good answer. I think I'd like to read it.

Comment: Huh. Seems like a lot of disagreement between the compilers there. Seems like some actual quotes from the standard would indeed be relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From cppreference's description of [enums](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> Values of unscoped enumeration type are implicitly-convertible to integral types. If the underlying type is not fixed, the value is convertible to the first type from the following list able to hold their entire value range: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, or `unsigned long long`, extended integer types with higher conversion rank (in rank order, signed given preference over unsigned) (since C++11). If the underlying type is fixed, the values can be converted to their underlying type (preferred in overload resolution), which can then be promoted.

So you're right about which overload of `foo` will be selected, but you're wrong that there's no implicit conversion taking place. A `days` is still a different type from an `unsigned char`, but it will implicitly convert to one.

You're also wrong that, in the event that the implementation happens to select `unsigned char` as the underlying type for `enum Tokens`, it will therefore implicitly convert to `unsigned char`. Implicit conversion to a narrower underlying type than `int` *only* occurs if you fix the underlying type yourself instead of letting the implementation decide.

The text from the Primer you quoted is only describing the situation when you don't explicitly specify an underlying type.

Quotes from the [draft standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#def:integral_promotion), expr.conv.prom:

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration ([dcl.enum]): `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, or `unsigned long long int`. If none of the types in that list can represent all the values of the enumeration, a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of the extended integer type with lowest integer conversion rank ([conv.rank]) greater than the rank of `long long` in which all the values of the enumeration can be represented. If there are two such extended types, the signed one is chosen.
>
> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is fixed ([dcl.enum]) can be converted to a prvalue of its underlying type. Moreover, if integral promotion can be applied to its underlying type, a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is fixed can also be converted to a prvalue of the promoted underlying type.

And from [over.ics.rank](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank):

> A conversion that promotes an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed to its underlying type is better than one that promotes to the promoted underlying type, if the two are different.

Comment: So I understood that there's always an implicit conversion from the enumerators (un-scoped enums) to the underlying type. And if a function takes an `int` for example and we call it passing an enumerator of an un-scoped `enum` type whose underlying type is for example `unsigned char` then first, the enumerator value is implicitly converted to (underlying type) `unsigned char` then promoted to `int` (integral promotion) finally passed to the function as an `int` argument. Right?